# How to know when font family was changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-draft-wysiwyg

I'm using the react-draft-wysiwyg library and I need to know whenever the font family gets changed via the menu/dropdown.

I was hoping there would be an onChange callback on fontFamily itself.

**Like this:**

```
<Editor
    ...
      toolbar={{
          options: [
               ...
               "fontFamily",
          ],
          ...
          fontFamily: {
            options: this.state.fonts.map((f) => f.name),
            className: undefined,
            component: undefined,
            dropdownClassName: undefined,
            onChange: (newFont) => { // do something }
          },
   }}
/>
```

But there is no onChange property on fontFamily itself.

How would I go about listening for anytime the font family gets changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way. I ended up forking react-draft-wysiwyg (since it is already un-maintained) and implemented the functionality.